# Blocked system-critical thread has been detected, blockedFor=12s

Tags: ignite

Recently we had faced some problems with our ignite cluster, sometime Nodes threw some logs message like below:
Blocked system-critical thread has been detected. This can lead to cluster-wide undefined behaviour [workerName=ttl-cleanup-worker, threadName=ttl-cleanup-worker-#120, blockedFor=12s]
it seem that the system was blocked. So do you have ever faced this issues? Can we disscuss about this? "blockedFor=12s]" mean whole system was halt in 12s?

I have already try to research about this problem

Comment: Too little information. The message means that the thread (not whole application) has been blocked. Probably some partition was locked by another process. If you'd like to investigate this, please create a JIRA ticket at https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/IGNITE/ and submit the full logs there + thread dumps.